# Django enum attribute equality

Tags: python, django, enums

I'm using enums in a django model, like:

```
class AwesomeNess(Enum):
    slight = "SLIGHT"
    very = "VERY"

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    awesomeness = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=[(tag.value, tag.name) for tag in AwesomeNess],
        default=AwesomeNess.slight
    )
```

This works fine when I use Django's filter function, like:

```
d = Choice.objects.filter(awesomeness=AwesomeNess.slight)
```

However, it does not work if I do:

```
choice_obj = Choice.objects.get(id=1)
choice_obj.awesomeness == AwesomeNess.slight # will return False
choice_obj.awesomeness == "AwesomeNess.slight" # will return True
```

Since values are stored as strings, it looks like Django forgets to cast them back to an enum when returning the data.
This gives inconsistencies when coding, since django model filters can query on the enum, while attribute equality filtering requires me to use the stringed representation of the enum.

EDIT: The enums are imported from another model class, so replacing it with Django's built-in choices class is not an option.

EDIT2: As i'm investigating this, I'm also noticing the following:

```
myobj = Choice.objects.get(id=1)
myobj.awesomeness  # <<-- string type
myobj.awesomeness =  AwesomeNess.very <<-- object changes type to enum
myobj.save()
myobj2 = Choice.objects.get(id=1) <<-- upon reload from db, the updated value is returned as string
```

As a novice Django user, this seems incredibly dangerous to me, and isn't mentioned in any of the "how to use enums with django" articles I've read. Is this simply due to the fact that I'm on a too old Django version?

Is there a way around this? Am I doing something very wrong? Pointers appreciated!
oh, bwt: this is on Django 2.2.24. Maybe later versions have improved enum support?

Comment: Django 3+ has built-in support for enumeration types for choices https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types, not that it answers your question, sorry

Answer (score 4):

The reason that this happens is because the choices call `str` on the value that is given, and this thus means it will store `"AwesomeNess.slight"` as a string (if that is set as default).

Since [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), you can work with a [**`TextChoices`** class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) which is quite the same as using an `Enum`. You thus can define a `TextChoices` model with:

```
class Choice(models.Model):

    class AwesomNess(models.TextChoices):
        SLIGHT = 'SLIGHT', 'slight'
        VERY = 'VERY', 'very'

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    awesomeness = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=AwesomeNess.choices,
        default=AwesomeNess.SLIGHT
    )
```

for older versions, you need to specify that you work with the *value* of the `AwesomeNess`:

```
class AwesomeNess(Enum):
    slight = 'SLIGHT'
    very = 'VERY'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    awesomeness = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=[(tag.value, tag.name) for tag in AwesomeNess],
        default=AwesomeNess.slight.value
    )
```

Comment: even when using `tag.value, tag.name` there are inconsistencies between strings and enum depending on the state of the model object, see EDIT2 above in OP. We concluded that using Enums in any form with django 2.x is simply too dangerous.

Comment: @Trondh: yes, you should always use `.value`. In the form that is not necessary, since the form will automatically use the value that is associate with the text. What you could do is simply define the constants in a class (so *without* the enum logic), and thus use these as constants.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep that's what we kindof ended up doing. The intricasies between stringed and enumed representation depending on object state was just too much of a risk for us. We'll circle back to using "native" Enums after we've upgraded to 3.x. Thanks for all comments and suggestions!